# How can I get string from parse object?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, parse-platform

```
private void getFriendRequests(){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FriendRequests");
    query.whereEqualTo("To",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    query.whereNotEqualTo("Accepted", true);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                fillFriendRequests(objects);
                displayFriendRequest();
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
}

private void fillFriendRequests(List<ParseObject> list){
    for(ParseObject object:list){
         frArrayStrings.add(object.getString("From"));
    }
public void displayFriendRequest(){
    friendRequestView= (ListView)mview.findViewById(R.id.listViewFriendReqs);
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,frArrayStrings);
    friendRequestView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    setClickListenter();
}
```

I cannot understand why I get nothing even there is a string in the query.
I certainly named the query right but when I see the 
object.getString("From");in textview, there is nothing there and the textsize is 0. Can you guys help out what's wrong with my code?